# Load SoundCloud Iframe when seen

Tags: javascript, iframe, soundcloud

I have several SoundCloud iframes in a div. I am looking to load them only when the div is being seen. Currently I am loading them through a method that I found online which loads them one by one but still doesn't really do me justice.

What I am looking to do is to lower the load time on the site when its loaded. Since SoundCloud slows the website down this should make it faster.

Something close to eager loading for iframes.

Here is what I have so far :

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-cell">
    <div class="div-img-content">
        <div class="soundcloud-wrapper" id="236517781"></div>   
  </div>    
    <div class="div-icon-name">
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/assets/gallery_content/icon-music.png" alt="">
    Terryl E
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function loadSoundcloud () {
  $(".soundcloud-wrapper").each(function() {
    var URL = $(this).attr('id');
        var htm = '<iframe width="100%" height="200px" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + URL +'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        $(this).html(htm).fitVids().removeClass('.loading');
    });
}
```

Comment: Look at this please :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: This only works for JS script files.  Something to eager load  iframes.

Comment: Try with lazyload jquery plugin

Answer (score 1):

With the encouragement of Melvita,  I went with [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) and dropped my load time by half!.  It also reduced the the initial request from 400 to 48.

Thanks so much.